# How does one find the greatest speed?

Tags: calculus

If a an object defined by a function of

$$v(t)=3\sin(0.5t)-4\cos(3.5t)$$

from $0$ to $3$ how would find the greatest speed gained.

Wouldn't it be the maxiumum point on the graph of $v(t)$?

Comment: please improve question quality by adding what you've tried, or the way that you are thinking how to approach this problem

Comment: Yes, it is precisely maximum of that function. It exist, because of [extreme value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem). Usual way to find it is to compare all zeros of the derivative (local maxima).

Comment: In general the greatest speed will be the maximum of $|v(t)|$, not necessarily the maximum of $v(t)$.  (Speed $|v(t)|$ is unsigned, while velocity $v(t)$ can be positive or negative).  In this case, the maximum speed and the maximum velocity are equal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will be the maximum of the graph of $v(t)$, but we can also calculate it more easily by the extreme value theorem that states that a function $f(x)$  has $f'(x)$ =0 at its local maxima and minima.               (This can be easily proved since on either sides its dervative's signs are opposite at maxima and minima)

In this case the acceleration ($v'(t)$)will be 0 at the required point. 
Thus acceleration
$a(t)$=$v'(t)$
=3×0.5cos(0.5t)+4×3.5sin(3.5t).
(By chain rule)

Thus 1.5cos(0.5t)+14sin(3.5t)=0 .

We solve it using trigonometry to find $ t$ in between 0 and  3. Then we find maximum velocity $v(t)$. Also we should check if its maximum or minimum . If minimum then there must be a maximum at end point.
Hope this helps to understand.

Comment: Sorry I found maximum velocity.